# Oracle - Filtering based on column value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following table for which I would like to obtain result based on the number of different **TYPE**s available for every **CONTRACT_ID**.

**Table:**

```
______________________________________________________________________________________
|Source             |   CONTRACT_ID |   TYPE        |   ADDRESS |   PHONE           |
______________________________________________________________________________________
|Source1            |   1234        |   INSURED     |   unique1 |   4321            |
______________________________________________________________________________________
|Source1            |   1234        |   INSURED     |   unique1 |   4321            |
______________________________________________________________________________________
|Source1            |   1234        |   DRIVER      |   unique1 |   4321            |
______________________________________________________________________________________
|Source1            |   1234        |   INSURED     |   unique1 |   4321            |
______________________________________________________________________________________
|Source2            |   2345        |   INSURED     |   unique2 |   5678            |
______________________________________________________________________________________
|Source2            |   2345        |   DRIVER      |   unique2 |   5678            |
______________________________________________________________________________________
|Source2            |   2345        |   CONTRACT    |   unique2 |   5678            |
______________________________________________________________________________________
```

**Result:**

```
______________________________________________________________________________________
|Source             |   CONTRACT_ID |   ROLES       |   ADDRESS |   PHONE           |
______________________________________________________________________________________
|Source1            |   1234        |   2           |   unique1 |   4321            |
______________________________________________________________________________________
|Source2            |   2345        |   3           |   unique2 |   5678            |
______________________________________________________________________________________
```

i.e, The **ROLES** column in the result table should be the number of different **TYPE**s for a distinct **CONTRACT_ID**.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have surfed but still couldnt get any idea on how to count the number of different varchar values @KaushikNayak!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT max(source) , contract_id ,
count( DISTINCT type) roles , max(address), max(phone) 
FROM Table group by contract_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `count(distinct)`:

```
select Source, CONTRACT_ID, ADDRESS, PHONE, count(distinct type) as roles
from t
group by Source, CONTRACT_ID, ADDRESS, PHONE  ;
```

This is not "filtering".  It is "aggregation".